# How to create index and type in elastic search - I've tried answers provided until now and they don't work

Tags: java, elasticsearch, postman

So, I've tried `curl -XPUT "https://localhost:9200/myIndex/myTopic"`, but that doesn't work.
It gives me **405 error** saying that only POST method is available. By the solutions and comments I've read, I guess that was working until  some patch or something. So how should I do it now?
Thanks in advance.

P.S I only need type, since I can create index. Then I'll run the program that will put data into that data automatically, so I don't need anything after "/myTopic".

Comment: which `Elasticsearch` version are you using ?

Comment: I was using 6.7, but I tried with the newest version, and I managed somehow. It was in vain thought because Json file that I've got from someone, is really just logs in Json, so I can't parse it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

you need to call only as `curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/myIndex?pretty"` no need to append anything like /myTopic.

Please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is, I am learning this by watching some tutorial.  Guy there uses older Maven dependecy (below 7.x) and is using IndexRequest(index: myIndex, type: myType) in Java which is deprecated in new versions.

Comment: Not sure which tutorial your following but in elastic curl request it only need index name. Even you can check older references for elasticsearch  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/indices-create-index.html.

Comment: He just typed in the API client for PUT method "/twitter", and then ran it and created "twitter" index. Then he type "/twitter/tweets", also PUT method, and created type "\tweets". Then he used IndexRequest("twitter", "tweets") and that's it. So I first tried doing that in Postman (twitter/tweets), but I got **405 error**, because of appending, like you said. So I'm trying to find some other way to do what he did.